# Is there a way to tag already uploaded artwork on Steam with the game title?

Tags: steam

I have uploaded some artworks to my Steam profile.

During the uploading process, there are multiple options one can choose from, starting with having to choose a game, or opting for it being non-game-specific:

> [image: cropped part of screenshot of Steam's interface showing the game selection prompt]
>
> **SELECT WHICH GAME YOU WANT TO UPLOAD ARTWORK FOR**
> Enter the game's name<sup>1</sup>
> <kbd>Search games</kbd>                                                 
> Or
> <kbd>**Not Game Specific**</kbd>
> (This artwork is not related to any product on Steam. This is a good option for off-topic images.)

When you select the latter option, the file will only show on your profile.
If you select the first option, you can later still choose between uploading the artwork to the Community Hub, or exclusively to your profile:

> [image: cropped part of screenshot of Steam's interface asking where you want to save your artwork]
>
> ***NEW!** Is this artwork not directly related to this product? Instead of posting to a community hub, you can upload it to your profile, for use in your Artwork Showcase. You can also upload artwork **directly from your Profile** under Artwork.*
>
> <kbd>Cancel</kbd> <kbd>Save artwork to my profile</kbd> Or <kbd>Save artwork to Community Hub</kbd>

If you select the first option—"*Save artwork to my profile*"—it will apparently also get rid of the game tag, which, for organizational purposes, I'd like to keep. It then only shows:

> [image: cropped part of screenshot of Steam's interface showing the only tag applied to artwork if you choose to publish on your profile]
>
> Tags: **Steam Artwork**

**Is there a way I can still add a game tag to my uploaded artworks?**

If so, I would also like to be able to submit it to that game's Community Hub. Is there any chance to do so?

---

<sup>1. The silly and annoying thing is that you can only select activated games from your own library—making the comment for the second option nonsensical. I wanted to upload a Frostpunk screenshot with the appropriate tag after its Free Weekend, but that seems to be impossible. If someone knows how to circumvent this, please let me know.</sup>